# VBscript to get info from pc

Tags: vbscript

Hello I´m writing this script where i need Serial number, IP address, login user, produkt key from office, autoroute to a text file. I have begun to write a script but having some issues. Not a done script but im kinda stuck to here.

Here´s the script:

```
    On Error Resume Next

    Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
    Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

    arrComputers = Array("localhost")
    For Each strComputer In arrComputers

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService1.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystemProduct", "WQL", _ wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)                         
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService2.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem", "WQL", _ wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

    Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:\\" & strCoputer & ".\root\CIMV2" )
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration", "WQL", _ wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

    next

    For Each objItem In colItems2

    Dim fso, tf
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set tf = fso.CreateTextFile ("c:\" & objItem.UserName & ".txt", True)
    tf.Write "Username: " & objItem.UserName
    tf.WriteBlankLines(1)
    tf.Write "Hostname: " & objItem.Name
    tf.WriteBlankLines(1)
    tf.Write "Domain: " & objItem.Domain
    tf.WriteBlankLines(2)

    next 

    For Each objItem In colItems1

    tf.Write "Serial: " & objItem.IdentifyingNumber
    tf.WriteBlankLines(1)
    tf.Write "Model: " & objItem.Name
    tf.WriteBlankLines(2)  
    tf.Write "Vendor: " & objItem.Vendor
    tf.WriteBlankLines(1)   
    tf.Write "Version: " & objItem.Version
    tf.WriteBlankLines(2)  

    Next

    For Each objItem In colItems3

    tf.Write "IP Address: " & objItem.IPAddress
    tf.WriteBlankLines(1)
    tf.Close

    next
```

Comment: what info is remaining to get and where you stucked

Comment: I still need the licens from office, autoroute and get it in a text file. The setup now it wont write to text file.

Comment: refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221405.aspx#BKMK_LogFileSections

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has created a free tool called Scriptomatic which automatically creates vbscript code for such kind of task. You can download scriptomatic from the below location.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=12028